# Sqlite nodejs - Queries with multiple parameters

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Here is a sample request that it is possible to do with [sqlite3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3) :

```
  var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO lorem VALUES (?)");
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      stmt.run("Ipsum " + i);
  }
  stmt.finalize();
```

Is it possible to pass different parameters in the query ?

```
"INSERT INTO ? (?) VALUES (?)"
```

Here is my request to optimize :

```
var req = 'INSERT INTO ' + nameTable + ' (';

for (var cle in ligne) {
    req += cle + ', ';
}
substring(1,req.lenght-2); 
req += ') VALUES ('

for (var cle in ligne) {
    req += ligne[cle] + ', ';
}
substring(1,req.lenght-2); // On supprime la virgule de la fin
req += ');';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't; query parameters are expressions and can't be used as identifiers.

Unless you're writing a generic database tool, however, this is usually a sign of bad design. It usually means that you need to merge the tables and add columns for the values you're trying to use as table names.

Comment: It is precisely a database tool. I have no problems with the structure of my database . And is it possible to do that : `"INSERT INTO table (?) VALUES (?)"` ?

Comment: @MartinLbc No. The columns to insert is a list of identifiers, not expressions.